# How to convert the following gstreamer commandline into c

Tags: c, gstreamer

> gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-level=3 dvbsrc modulation='QAM 256'
>   frequency=147000000 ! decodebin name=demux demux. ! queue !
>   audioresample ! audioconvert ! voaacenc ! mux. mpegtsmux name=mux
>   ! udpsink host=127.0.0.0 port=22 demux. ! queue ! videoconvert !
>   videoscale ! x264enc bitrate=1240 tune=zerolatency
>   !video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,profile=high,width=540,height=380,key-int-max=15
>   ! mux.

I want to convert into c with the same thing.

I am trying -:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>

static gboolean bus_call (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, gpointer data)
{
  GMainLoop *loop = (GMainLoop *) data;

  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {

    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
      g_print ("End of stream\n");
      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;

    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
      gchar  *debug;
      GError *error;

      gst_message_parse_error (msg, &error, &debug);
      g_free (debug);

      g_printerr ("Error: %s\n", error->message);
      g_error_free (error);

      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }

  return TRUE;
}


int main (gint   argc, gchar *argv[])
{
  GMainLoop *loop;
  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *demuxer,*dec,*vdqueue,*adqueue, *conv, *sink;
  GstBus *bus;

  /* init GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);
  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);


  /* setup */

  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline");
  bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
  gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
  gst_object_unref (bus);

  source = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "filesource");
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "location", argv[1], NULL);

  g_printerr ("source is: %s \n",argv[1]);

  //demuxer = gst_element_factory_make ("avidemux", "avi-demuxer");
  demuxer  = gst_element_factory_make ("oggdemux",      "ogg-demuxer");
  vdqueue = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", "video-queue");
  adqueue = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", "audio-queue");

  dec = gst_element_factory_make ("vorbisdec",     "vorbis-decoder");
  conv  = gst_element_factory_make ("audioconvert",  "converter");
  sink  = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "audio-output");


/*  g_object_set (pipeline->mux,"max-delay", (guint64)0,NULL);
    g_object_set (pipeline->mux,"max-page-delay",(guint64)0,NULL);
*/

  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "caps",
  gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw",
                                     "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB16",
                                     "width", G_TYPE_INT, 640,
                                     "height", G_TYPE_INT, 480,
                                     "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 0, 1,
                                     NULL), NULL); 

  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline),source,demuxer,vdqueue,adqueue,dec,conv,sink, NULL);
  gst_element_link (source, demuxer);
  gst_element_link (demuxer, vdqueue);
  gst_element_link (vdqueue, adqueue);
  gst_element_link (adqueue, dec);
  gst_element_link (dec, conv);
  gst_element_link (conv, sink);
  /* run */
 // g_printerr ("pipeline is: %s \n",pipeline);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  /* cleanup */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give us more info and try to form the question a little bit more specific

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no request included, and no reasonable attempt to illustrate prior attempts made or problems encountered.